# Extract nth Packet From a Pacp File

Tags: linux, centos6.5, pcap, tshark

Is there any command line tool to extract the n th packet from a pcap file?

I am on CentOS 6.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extract it and print it out, or extract it into a new pcap file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

> tshark -r file.pcap -R "frame.number == n"

Hope this was helpful.